# Can we add a common Jump list Task to all running applications on WIndows 7+

Tags: windows, taskbar, jump-list

Before Windows 7 came, right clicking on any application on taskbar use to popup a menu like shown in picture below.

[image]

All the menu items that you see below 'maximize' and above 'close' are the custom menu that I had added.  I had developed a system tool called [PMW(process Manager for windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/processpriority/)) that would add these menu's to *all* the running applications.

With Windows 7 and above these kind of context menu is gone. Old menu comes only when we do shift key+ right click. Now After 4-5 years I have been thinking to upgrade this tool.

I was wondering if Windows jump list provides an option to add a generic task to all application? If it does allows then perhaps I update this tool for Windows.

My understanding is with JumpList I can add two types of menu one is URLs/Files and second is Task. and both of these *perhaps* would be part of only application that you developing. I think *perhaps* I cant inject a few my task into the jump list of all other applications. Can I?

Comment: Did you do any research before asking? What did you find out?

Comment: read through a few article and it mentioned that task can be added but it wasnt clearly mentioned that generic task can be added to all running application. I think what it meant was, task can be added to onyl your own applcaition not all. Otherwise when I see the the jump list of browsers or Outlook they have task like "launch new private tab" or "compose new email"  they are specific to their own apps. So far I have not seen any task that's generalized and found in multiple apps other Close Window and Unpin/Pin from/to taskbar.

Comment: Old context menu of Windows Application can still be seen with Shift + right click. This tool used to inject its own menus into Context menu of all apps using the hooks, Was wondering if a global hook can help to do the same with jump list.

Comment: @ArifAliSaiyed I guess you didn't manage to find any solution which is sad because this tool is very handy. I was wondering though, why the latest version doesn't work on windows 10? It adds the commands to the classic context menu but none of the commands are effective.. Do you know if this could be fixed? Thanks for your past efforts

Comment: @ArifAliSaiyed Actually the commands work but not on all applications.. I was wondering if we could add a Mute application command